# Printing species name from fasta file heading in an output file using biopython (for multiple files)

Tags: python, biopython

I'm having trouble printing the species name from my fasta files

The input file is this:

```
>NP_842573.1 chromosomal replication initiator DnaA [Bacillus anthracis str. Ames]
MENISDLWNSALKELEKKVSKPSYETWLKSTTAHNLKKDVLTITAPNEFARDWLESHYSELISETLYDLTGAKLAIRFIIPQSQAEEEIDLPPAKPNAAQDDSNHLPQSMLNPKYTFDTFVIGSGNRFAHAASLAVAEAPAKAYNPLFIYGGVGLGKTHLMHAIGHYVIEHNPNAKVVYLSSEKFTNEFINSIRDNKAVDFRNKYRNVDVLLIDDIQFLAGKEQTQEEFFHTFNALHEESKQIVISSDRPPKEIPTLEDRLRSRFEWGLITDITPPDLETRIAILRKKAKAEGLDIPNEVMLYIANQIDSNIRELEGALIRVVAYSSLINKDINADLAAEALKDIIPNSKPKIISIYDIQKAVGDVYQVKLEDFKAKKRTKSVAFPRQIAMYLSRELTDSSLPKIGEEFGGRDHTTVIHAHEKISKLLKTDTQLQKQVEEINDILK
```

And a section of my output file looks like this (GCF...faa is the file name)

```
Y,2.798738459583378,GCF_000014005.1_ASM1400v1_protein.faa
```

I'd really like to print the species name [Bacillus anthracis str. Ames] as well as the file name.

The line which I need to edit is this:

```
file.write ('\nY,' + str(pY) +  ',' + str(FILE))
```

Which prints a couple of variables and then the string of the file name.

But I'm struggling to find a way of outputting the string between the square brackets in the header of the fasta file, using biopython.

Comment: You can likely extract this via `record.description.split('[', 1)[1].split(']', 1)[0]` or similar

Comment: pY is the percentage of the amino acid Tyrosine across the proteome. As such there is quite a bit of context code, I'm not sure if it's relevant but I can put it if you'd like!

Thanks I will try the record description method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris_Rands pointed out in the comments, the answer is:

```
 record.description.split('[', 1)[1].split(']', 1)[0]
```